# Nestjs Config validation error: in test even that process.env set in code

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

App.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import * as Joi from 'joi';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      validationSchema: Joi.object({
        SOME_ENV_VARIABLE: Joi.string().required(),
      }),
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.e2e-spec.ts:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { AppModule } from './../src/app.module';

describe('AppController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    process.env.SOME_ENV_VARIABLE = 'kuku';
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  it('/ (GET)', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer()).get('/').expect(200).expect('kuku');
  });
});
```

If I run this test regularly the test fails:

```
 npm run test:e2e
```

with the following error:
 `Config validation error: "SOME_ENV_VARIABLE" is required`

But if I run the test with env

```
export SOME_ENV_VARIABLE=kuku && npm run test:e2e
```

the test passes

I don't understand why

`process.env.SOME_ENV_VARIABLE = 'kuku';`

If I run the test without the validationSchema it works fine in both cases

Comment: It may happen because nest is running validation before you manually set this variable in the code. Try to set some breakpoints in the code and verify the behaviour with the debugger. I do not have time to check my hypothesis now, but I think that because `ConfigModule` is global, validation will run at the moment when you are importing `AppModule` into the test file

Comment: You totally right, the validate method is running at the "import" time and because of that it will run only once for the entire test file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@moti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9088658/moti) mentioned the validate method is running at the Import time.
So the only way to test it against multiple different scenarios is to require it on the fly during the test:

Instead of:

```
import { AppModule } from "../src/app.module";
```

Do:

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    process.env.SOME_ENV_VARIABLE = 'kuku';
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    jest.requireActual("../src/app.module");
});
```

This way it will run with the overridden environment variable